# Will sql injection works if ' " \ are filtered

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I am studing security and ethical hacking. And I have noticed that most of sql injection attacks uses " ' \ will it work if I filtered these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of SQL injection examples use the `;DROP TABLE students` payload which is not even a thing in many software setups. This is just an example.

You are making a very common mistake, confusing an injection (a **possibility** to inject an unwanted code into the SQL query) with an exploit (the **actual payload** to be injected with a purpose of breaking into a system).

That's two completely different matters.

So, an injection is just a possibility. And it is irrelevant to *any* characters. Once injection is there, then an infinite number of exploits possible, all depends on the situation. Some of them will require anything but ' and \ symbols and some will need them.

What takeaway you can make from the statements above? **One should protect from injections, not exploits.** Fighting characters is a losing game. Fight the possibility.

Once an application is not protected from injections, it will be hacked, with one exploit or another, using one character or another. But once it is protected, it is protected from all exploits at once, no matter which character used.